# how to call web service in ajax properly?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

ok, here is what i am trying to do, i want to get all user from active directory and put it in the list,so i would call a web service from ajax, to get all user and put it the list string, and later on i want to use jquery autocomplete in the textbox base on list of user which i got before.

this is what i do :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            // Load data then initialize plugin:
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SvcADUser.asmx/GetADUserList',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (source) {

                var countriesArray = $.map(source, function (value) { return { value: value }; }),
                    countries = $.map(source, function (value) { return value; });

                // Setup jQuery ajax mock:
                $.mockjax({
                    url: '*',
                    responseTime: 200,
                    response: function (settings) {
                        var query = settings.data.query,
                            queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
                            suggestions = $.grep(countries, function (country) {
                                return country.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) !== -1;
                            }),
                            response = {
                                query: query,
                                suggestions: suggestions
                            };

                        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
                    }
                });



                // Initialize autocomplete with local lookup:
                $('#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').autocomplete({
                    lookup: countriesArray,
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                        $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                    }
                });

            });

        }());

    }());
```

but this throw me an error, `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:60525/SvcADUser.asmx/GetADUserList"`, if i change the url to SvcADUser.asmx, it does not give an error, but give me no result.

what i do wrong here? btw here is my web service code :

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SvcADUser : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetADUserList(string keyword)
        {
            List<string> alluser = new List<string>();

            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "weekendinc.com"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                        alluser.Add((string)de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            var filtereduser = alluser.Where(usr => usr.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower()));

            return filtereduser.ToList();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the screen output / error when you run the asmx file in debug and enter the keyword manually?

Comment: nope, my asmx file did not returned errors, it works well, it return me list of user.

Comment: ok the web service is working. Try and put a success and error in your ajax. See if you can catch response.d and retrieve data from it. I struggled for some time to get it right myself, so I ended up writing a [blog post](http://wimombelets.blogspot.be/2013/03/consuming-aspnet-web-services-with-ajax.html) about it so I wouldn't forget. Perhaps you'll find it of some use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: '{keyword:"test"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            url: 'SvcADUser.asmx/GetADUserList',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
        });
```

Comment: for some reason your code working, is it because JQuery statement before .ajax?

Comment: i think keypoints are :
(1.)make sure url is correct.
(2.)method GetADUserList(string keyword) has param 'keyword', 
so you have to post data for it, like this --> data:'{keyword:"test"}'